# Why has my game video, captured with OBS/Win10 DVR, a black screen in iMovie/WindowsMovieMaker?

Tags: codec, imovie, video-capture, windows-movie-maker, obs

I am capturing games on my Windows 10 PC with [Open Broadcast Software](https://obsproject.com/) and x264 codec. My problem is that as soon as I import a video.mp4 file to iMovie or WindowsMovieMaker for editing, it is black, but has sound.

But when I watch it with Quicktime or Windows Video it works without a problem.

A while ago it worked - but I do not know if it was my upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 or a newer version of OBS.

Things i tried:

- export it into .mov with Quicktime - didn't work - after rendering an non sense error message á la "did not work"
- reset OBS settings
- deinstall and install fresh OBS
- download h264 codec on windows, but it's just an .exe file - dunno what to do with it

So what am I doing wrong? Do you have any questions or need informations to help me that I didn't provided yet?

**Update**: Tried to capture a game video with Windows 10s new game capture feature and Windows Movie Maker has same problem with this video as well. Black screen -.- 
Looks like OBS is not the problem.

**Update 2**: Here is the media info from one of my test files. It is recorded with OBS and saved to Fraps folder, it is not recorded with Fraps - but I guess that does not matter anyway.

```
General
Complete name                            : D:\Fraps\video.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.27 MiB
Duration                                 : 9s 499ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 122 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
Writing application                      : Open Broadcaster Software v0.657b

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Muxing mode                              : Container profile=High@3.1
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 9s 499ms
Source duration                          : 9s 466ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 29.412 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.303 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.016
Stream size                              : 1.12 MiB (88%)
Source stream size                       : 1.12 MiB (88%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 146 r2538 121396c
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=cbr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=1000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=1000 / vbv_bufsize=1000 / nal_hrd=none / filler=1 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : sYCC
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
mdhd_Duration                            : 9499

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 9s 487ms
Source duration                          : 9s 429ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Nominal bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               :  channel0
Channel(s)_Original                      : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Source stream size                       : 140 KiB (11%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-17 23:47:57
```

And this is recorded with [Win10 Game Capture Feature](https://support.xbox.com/de-DE/xbox-on-windows/social/record-game-clips-game-dvr-windows-10):

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\User\Videos\Captures\Sid Meier's ~ Pirates! 18.01.2016 01_08_40.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp41/isom)
File size                                : 7.06 MiB
Duration                                 : 30s 534ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 941 Kbps
Movie name                               : Sid Meier's ~ Pirates!
Performer                                : Microsoft Game DVR
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
Xtra                                     : {64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 27

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=29
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 30s 522ms
Source duration                          : 30s 500ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 810 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 960 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 29.970 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.030 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.049
Stream size                              : 6.58 MiB (93%)
Source stream size                       : 6.58 MiB (93%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
mdhd_Duration                            : 30522

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 30s 534ms
Source duration                          : 30s 534ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 481 KiB (7%)
Source stream size                       : 481 KiB (7%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-01-18 00:08:40
mdhd_Duration                            : 30534
```

**Update 3**: This is a screenshot of my Windows Movie Maker. Like you see at the left a black screen and at the right first image of the movie, but that's all. And kinda wired thing is that I have with iMovie same problem. So it can not be a codec problem on my Windows 10 PC, but all capture apps have the same problem, well or all video editors...

[image: Windows Movie Maker Screenshot]

**Update 4**: Here is the media info of my .mkv file.

```
General
Unique ID                                : 242469772953486188448003563262617227499 (0xB669FAC94B0A3F6673840B2F750A90EB)
Complete name                            : C:\Users\User\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\Video-1.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 1.15 MiB
Duration                                 : 9s 566ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 005 Kbps
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.9.9
Writing library                          : libmkv 0.6.5

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 9s 567ms
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 476 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 130 r2273 b3065e6
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=0 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=300 / keyint_min=30 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=20000 / vbv_bufsize=25000 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : A_AAC
Duration                                 : 9s 566ms
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Comment: What does [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) say for the OBS captured file? Use View -> Text mode and paste the readout into your Q.

Comment: @Mulvya I added two sample file infos to my question.

Comment: @Mulvya I reencoded it with Handbrake into .m4v and now it works on iMovie as well. But I still do not get it why iMovie and Windows Movie Maker have problems with the original .mp4.
I tried Blender and there it works with original .mp4.

Answer (score 1):

The variable frame rate is all that stands out. Save future videos with constant frame rate. As for these ones, transcode using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)* to CFR MP4s:

```
ffmpeg -i currentvideo.mp4 -c:a copy -crf 16 -r 30 -fflags +genpts newvideo.mp4
```

*Get the 32-bit static build.

Comment: But why is Win10 game capture feature not working too? I've no settings there and this should work anyway. But I'll try your settings.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work either. Now I will try to reencode it with Handbrake and maybe it works...

Comment: It is kinda ridiculous - when I put it into .mkv container instead of .mp4 it works with Windows Movie Maker. Now I'll try it in iMovie.

Comment: Can you post the mediainfo of the MKV?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere else that people switched container .mp4 to .mkv and now it works with Windows Movie Player. But I do not why .mp4 does not work anymore with my Windows Movie Player.

And iMovie can not read or open .mkv - so I have still this problem.

With 'switched' I mean recoded it - I used Handbrake for it.